# Zero Pad a tuple(range(1,31))

Tags: python-3.x, zero-padding

I have a tuple of a range of numbers to indicate dates. I would like to zeropad the numbers so that the tuple if possible.

current results ( 1,2,3,4,5....10,11,12, etc) 
wanted results (01,02,03,... 10,11,12, etc)

Comment: Numbers don't work like that. You must convert them to strings first.

Comment: So the zeropad will be up to 9 right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [zfill](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=zfill).

```
>>> tuple(str(x).zfill(2) for x in range(1,31))
('01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30')
```

Comment: Just note that this will change the datatype to a string.